# asyncfileupload postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am using Asyncfileupload AJAX control, and want to know if there is anyway for me to automatically reload/refresh the current page after the file upload?

The whole thing loads in an iframe so not sure how to do this.

Thanks
Behrouz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/asyncfileupload/asyncfileupload.aspx) the `OnClientUploadComplete` callback javascript function will be executed when the file upload completes. So you could register for this event and refresh the current page using `window.location.reload();`.